# DateTimeField set as default field

Tags: python, django, postgresql

The following model needs a default value for its Date Field:

```
from django.utils import timezone as django_tz 
import psycopg2

class AvailabilityRuleOnce(AvailabilityRule):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'configuration'

    objects = AvailabilityRuleOnceManager()

    starting_time = django_models.DateTimeField(
        'Starting time for the rule', default=django_tz.now, blank=True
    )
    ending_time = django_models.DateTimeField(
        'Ending time for the rule', default=django_tz.now, blank=True
    )
```

When trying to apply the migrations, the following exception is thrown:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "ending_time" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp with time zone
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING ending_time::timestamp with time zone".
```

In the Django documentation they recommend this option and I have also tried other options that can be found on-line like adding "auto_now_add=True" but it is not working either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The real issue is that the migrations for Django do not erase the column with the datafield, which is necessary before updating the default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auto_now_true` is *the only* way to set the field to update on creation, [as the documentation states](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)

> The options `auto_now_add`, `auto_now`, and `default` are mutually exclusive. Any combination of these options will result in an error.

If `auto_now_true` isn't working the you need to raise a bug.

Comment: This worked but the actual problem was that I had to erase the original field from the database by commenting out the fields in the models within my code, migrating and migrating again with the new definition of the fields. The specific exception that I was getting was because the old existing fields in the database could not be casted to the new definition in the migrations file.